# How to Slide TextView in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can Anyone tell me how to slide textview in iphone in the same manner as we do with images.
I am developing an application in which I want to side the TextView. I have 5 TextViews.

Can anyone help me with this.....

Thanx in advance...

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Are you referring to the horizontal slide in the Photos app?

Comment: yes
Can you help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want a UIScrollView with paging enabled. Since with paging the view "stops on multiples of the view bounds" (according to the docs), you'd just line up your five text fields side-by-side, and make them the width of the visible area (the screen) inside a container view that sized to contain all 5.